# How to position background color?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the `background-colour: red`, which is part of the section "hero", go down to the end of the 3 vertically aligned boxes. I am not sure how to do this as it is not working. I have tried setting the `height: 100vh` but that does not seem to work. Rather, that moves the whole hero section down instead of just the background color.

If you have any questions or need more information, feel free to ask.

Current output:
[image: current output]

expected outcome:
[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #444444;
  background-color: blue;
}

a {
  color: #34b7a7;
}

a:hover {
  color: #51cdbe;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

#main {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #main {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}

#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: red;
}

#hero .container {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

#hero h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Andale Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 56px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 200px;
  color: #222222;
}


@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #hero:before {
    content: "";
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  #hero h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 36px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff
  }
}



#mainthree {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

#mainthree .block1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 320px;
  height: 460px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 470px;
  background-color: #f4ecfb;
}

#mainthree .block2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 320px;
  height: 460px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 470px;
  background-color: #FFE8F2;
}



#aboit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130vh;
  background-color: green;
}


#aboit .block3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 225px;
  height: 225px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 320px;
  background-color: #FFE8F2;
}

#aboit .block4 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 225px;
  height: 225px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 320px;
  background-color: #FFE8F2;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

#aboit .toixte {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 660px;
  right: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#aboit .toitle {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 660px;
  right: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="hero" class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
        <h1>Cakes By Tayla</h1>
    </div>
</section>


<section id="mainthree">    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block1"></div>
        <div class="block2"></div>
        <div class="block1"></div>
    </div>
</section>


<section id="aboit">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block3"></div>
        <div class="block3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block4"></div>
        <div class="block4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="toitle"><p><b>About Us</b></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="toixte"><p>We provide only the best cakes to our <br>customers. Each cake is made with love <br>and care, ensuring that our customers are <br>always taken care of. Our cakes are <br>available for pickup or, delivery applies if <br>you are in a certain area</p></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You want that to look like as per the image above!

Comment: Nope, that is the output. I want the background color red to go down to the end of the 3 boxes. The red section is #hero @AlwaysHelping

Comment: Add an image of your expected output please!

Comment: Result of given code is different than the output in the image you have attached.

Comment: @PranavRustagi Agreed. Yeah that why i asking about expected output from the OP.

Comment: I have added in the expected output @AlwaysHelping

Comment: Your code is already producing that expected output. Check your other CSS files interfering with this code!

Comment: that is my only CSS file. I just didn't include the whole file @AlwaysHelping

Comment: @AlwaysHelping is right. The code is already producing that output. It is just that, it gets distorted on smaller screen sizes.

Comment: Your problem is NOT reproducible (there are no issues with your code as per the expected output). Others are saying the same thing in the comment. Update your browser that might help.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I have tried this. I am really not sure why the outcome isn't the way I want it to be. Do you know of any way to change the height of the background color?

Answer (score 1):

Your code generates the expected output. But if that doesn't work for you, You can change css of block1 -> `bottom: 470px`. I think, if you increase the value of `bottom` you can get the expected output. Try. This may help you.

```
#mainthree .block1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 320px;
  height: 460px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 470px;
  background-color: white;
}

<section id="mainthree">    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block1"></div>
        <div class="block1"></div>
        <div class="block1"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: this is good but I need just the background to move down. @ddmmcc